# Minimum node cut (Igraph)

Tags: python, igraph

Igraphs G.mincut() function computes "the minimum set of **edges** which needs to be removed to disconnect the graph".

Is there a similar function to compute the minimum set of **nodes** which needs to be removed to disconnect the graph?

Networkx has [exactly that](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.connectivity.cuts.minimum_node_cut.html#networkx.algorithms.connectivity.cuts.minimum_node_cut), but I'd rather not convert between the two formats.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is called `minimum_size_separators`, http://igraph.org/python/doc/igraph.GraphBase-class.html#minimum_size_separators